# How to normalize/decompose a table that contains several repeated option fields

Tags: mysql, normalization, database-normalization

Say I have a table of motors from various vendors, and motor costs and option costs, and also whether a particular option is present in a particular motor or not.

How can I best structure this in SQL (MySQL)?

Example Table:

```
motor
------------ 
id
model
listprice
price
cost_base //base cost of motor
position
weight
option_1_present //does option1 exist on the motor?
option_1_cost    //cost of option1 if it is selected by the user
option_2_present
option_2_cost
option_3_present
option_3_cost
option_4_present
option_4_cost
option_5_present
option_5_cost
option_6_present
option_6_cost
```

Aside from normalization I am curious if I should be decomposing the fields into separate tables based on "cost" and "presence" factors.

So far, this design, will work for me, namely based on customer preferences (i.e. options 1, 3), I will look into the DB to select the motors which have those options and then come up with a price

so say `SELECT * from motor where option_1_present=1 and option_3_present=1`
then add up the costs.

Question

Are there any normalization/decomposition tasks that are to be done with this table?

Comment: presence of options - `tinyint(1)`, while cost is `decimal(10,2)`.  weight is `float`, others are `int` for id, of `varchar(60)` for model.  There may be other options at which point I assume the table will be extended a bit by adding those options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are breaking the cardinal rule of databases design.  You are not confirming to first normal form 1NF.

> As per First Normal Form, no two Rows of data must contain repeating group of information i.e each set of column must have a unique value, such that multiple columns cannot be used to fetch the same row. Each table should be organized into rows, and each row should have a primary key that distinguishes it as unique.

[Database Normalization](http://www.studytonight.com/dbms/database-normalization.php)

Rather you should break up (especially since you have indicated that there maybe options added) your presence of options into a `presence` table and add a bridge table between presence and motor.

```
motor
------------ 
id
model
listprice
price
cost_base //base cost of motor
position
weight

bridge
--------
bridgeid
motorid
presenceid

presence
------------ 
presenceid
option
cost
```

This way you do not have your presence option repeating the cost, etc in the motor table.  If you want to add another option it does not requiring locking to rebuild a large table since the presence table will only have a few records in it at any given time.  The bridge table will tell you for what motor specified by the user has what options.  Basically turning all data from horizontal to vertical.  Your queries will have to get a bit more complex, but this is a much cleaner, more scale-able approach.

Comment: thanks.  I cannot quite grasp the `multiple columns cannot be used to fetch the same row`.  Can you give an example?

Comment: thanks. I think I have focused on the wrong idea.  For example, will `select * from motor where column1 = X, column2 = Y` return the same row?  What does "same row" mean?  I mean I can always specify several values to be passed as parameters to SQL for several columns, and an SQL query will return either no rows, or some rows.  It can also return one row, but whether it is *same row*, or not does not make sense to me

Comment: One more question on that -- suppose for example that for motor X, a specific option costs $300.  But for motor Y, that same option costs $500.  As in, it costs a different amount to fit the same option onto different motor.  Will that change table design?  So far I am assuming that table decomposition came out of consideration that each option has a static price regardless of the choice of motor it is fitted onto.

Comment: do you know the cost ahead of time?  you would need to make a separate options table and associate each one of those with a presence (cost) that way you do not repeat each option in the presence table, just its associated ID from its own table...This is all about reducing the amount of redundant data

Comment: yes, cost is known.  and probably same presence table is fine, I don't want to get design too out of hand.